# Calculate certain records (Calculate Field)

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, arcgis-pro

I have records that need to be updated.
For this I select all records that are false and then process them with Calculate Field. The other records should not be changed.
The output has NULL in each record. I don't understand where the error is.
I also tried instead of `return ags` `else: continue`.

```
#select records for updating
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute("Strassenverzeichnis", "NEW_SELECTION", "AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03154003' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03154010' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03154011' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03154020' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03154023' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03154401' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03156003' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03156012' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03156013' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03156016' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03156017' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03158015' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03158024' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03158026' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03158029' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '15085010'", None)

#locale variables
inTable = "Straßenverzeichnis"
fieldName = "AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL"
expression = "upd(!AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL!)"
codeblock = """
def auf(liste):
    neu_liste = []
    for i in liste:
        neu_liste.append(upd(i))
    return neu_liste
    
def upd(ags):
    if ags == "03154003":
        return "03154028"
    elif ags ==  "03154010":
        return "03154028"
    elif ags ==  "03154011":
        return "03154027"
    elif ags ==  "03154020":
        return "03154027"
    elif ags ==  "03154023":
        return "03154027"
    elif ags ==  "03154401":
        return "03154016"
    elif ags ==  "03156003":
        return "03159004"
    elif ags ==  "03156012":
        return "03159036"
    elif ags ==  "03156013":
        return "03159036"
    elif ags ==  "03156016":
        return "03159036"
    elif ags ==  "03156017":
        return "03159002"
    elif ags ==  "03158015":
        return "03158039"
    elif ags == "03158024":
        return "03158040"
    elif ags ==  "03158026":
        return "03158039"
    elif ags ==  "03158029":
        return "03158040"
    elif ags ==  "15085010":
        return "15085330"
    return ags
"""
arcpy.CalculateField_management(inTable, fieldName, expression, "PYTHON3", codeblock)
```

Comment: before I just try to return the values. This also didnt work.

Comment: I edit the code to an version without the replace method.

Comment: One problem: the table name is spelled differently in the SelectLayerByAttribute command than it is in the inTable variable.

Comment: Also your `auf()` function appears not to be called by anything, make your code simpler, remove it.

Comment: Thank you a lot. It works now perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is code runs perfectly:

```
#select records for updating
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute("Strassenverzeichnis", "NEW_SELECTION", "AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03154003' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03154010' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03154011' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03154020' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03154023' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03154401' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03156003' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03156012' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03156013' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03156016' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03156017' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03158015' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03158024' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03158026' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '03158029' Or AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL = '15085010'", None)

#locale variables
inTable = "Strassenverzeichnis"
fieldName = "AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL"
expression = "upd(!AGS_NR_KOMMUNAL!)"
codeblock = """
def upd(ags):
    if ags == "03154003":
        return "03154028"
    elif ags ==  "03154010":
        return "03154028"
    elif ags ==  "03154011":
        return "03154027"
    elif ags ==  "03154020":
        return "03154027"
    elif ags ==  "03154023":
        return "03154027"
    elif ags ==  "03154401":
        return "03154016"
    elif ags ==  "03156003":
        return "03159004"
    elif ags ==  "03156012":
        return "03159036"
    elif ags ==  "03156013":
        return "03159036"
    elif ags ==  "03156016":
        return "03159036"
    elif ags ==  "03156017":
        return "03159002"
    elif ags ==  "03158015":
        return "03158039"
    elif ags == "03158024":
        return "03158040"
    elif ags ==  "03158026":
        return "03158039"
    elif ags ==  "03158029":
        return "03158040"
    elif ags ==  "15085010":
        return "15085330"
    return ags
"""
arcpy.CalculateField_management(inTable, fieldName, expression, "PYTHON3", codeblock)
```